# How to run Python command for all folders in a directory

Tags: python, shell

I am new to Linux and I want to execute my Python script on data that is stored in a set of folders. The command is as follows:

```
python find_ids.py -i "video1-11" --Report_file_path "Report/December/Dec_1_16.csv"
```

My videos are stored in a path:

- /video/month/video1/video1-11.mp4
- /video/month/video1/video1-12.mp4

and so on.

How can I write a Bash script/command that can execute my Python script on all the videos stored in the folder video1 and write the results of my script to the command line/into a file?

Comment: Starting a whole new process for the Python interpreter for every single file is maybe not ideal. Have you considered having a Python script that uses globbing or `Pathlib` to find the files of interest itself?

Comment: Good point, I did not think of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i in *.mp4
do
  python find_ids.py -i "${i%*.mp4}" --Report_file_path "Report/December/Dec_1_16.csv"
done
```

Loop through the MP4 files in the current working directory and strip the file extension *.mp4* before using it in the Python command.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `find` command to find your files and execute any desired command on them like this:

```
find /video/month/video1/ -type f -name '*mp4' -exec python find_ids.py -i "{}" --Report_file_path "Report/December/Dec_1_16.csv" \;
```